# Set Antd TextArea value to Tag component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have reactjs Antd form and I want to render Tag component inside TextArea similar to Select component! [image]

I tried to set value by

```
values.description = <Tag color="magenta">magenta</Tag>
this.props.form.setFieldsValue(values);
```

function but it displays [object Object] [[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOpOg.png)

```
<Form.Item label={<span>Description</span>}>
    {getFieldDecorator('description', {
                                  initialValue:''
                                   })(
   <TextArea maxLength={500} autosize={{ minRows: 4, maxRows: 4 }} 
                     placeholder={'Description'} />
                                    )}
 </Form.Item>
```

I expect to get the same result as with Select component [Antd Select Component](https://ant.design/components/select/)
Any ideas on how to do so?

Comment: I think this is close to what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52406423/7727586

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to do with a TextArea. What you are looking for is an [content editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) div, which is very easily done:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  <Tag color="magenta">magenta</Tag>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also provide some guidance on how to set value and take the value on form submit?

Comment: I used <Selcet> and changed some css 
`<Select`
    `mode="tags"`
   `tokenSeparators={[',']}`
   `size={'default'}`
    `dropdownStyle={{ display: 'none' }}`
    `style={{ width: '100%' }} >`
`</Select>`